# even after updating my spring project using maven i'm getting a red cross mark at top of my project root folder

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, maven

I found these errors in problem tab...

```
1.one or more contraints have not been satisfied
2.can't change version of project facet dynamic web module to 2.4
3.project configurations is not uptodate with pom.xml
```

Comment: can you try copying `settings.xml` file from your `maven/conf/settings.xml` to `C:/Users/Username/.m2` folder? I had similar issue once and it was resolved like this.

Comment: i did..still facing same issue

Comment: I will delete project, WITHOUT delete project content & re import maven project